# How to temporary stop Akka actor reading messages from mailbox

Tags: akka

I have an actor processing messages and storing its results via asynchronous API (ReactiveMongo). IE when computation is completed actor is asking ReactiveMongo to store computation result and that call is non blocking.

How can I stop actor processing next messages until last ReactiveMongo request feature will be completed? Also mailbox should be able to receive incoming messages.

Comment: Does ReactiveMongo provide an API to check whether the request feature is completed?

Comment: Yes, insert call immediately returns Feature[WriteResult]. Basically I can add listener on feature.oncomplete and when it will be resolved I have to call something to activate actor back - this is one question. And another question how to stop actor after insert call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Blocking solution**

Simple and wrong answer: you can do this by blocking the actor, just call Await (or whatever similar method in the language do you use).

It is wrong because **Do not block inside the actor**.

**Not blocking solution**

Master\Worker pattern is a good for this problem: http://letitcrash.com/post/29044669086/balancing-workload-across-nodes-with-akka-2

So your **worker actor** will send the "*Work Done*" message after  ReactiveMongo request feature completion. Then **master** actor will send new "*Do this work*" message to the worker.

Comment: Thanks a lot, worker pulling job from master is much better than what I designed this morning.